# Salesforce MarketingCloud SDK/MobilePush SDK Data Protection Modes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush, push, gdpr

I see in the documentation of Marketing cloud:

> The MobilePush SDK supports three privacy modes that may affect your
>   application’s usage of MobilePush.
>
> Right to be Forgotten
>
> Restriction of Processing
>
> Do Not Track
>
> Each mode restricts the functionality of the MobilePush SDK and may
>   limit your customers’ experience.

I couldn't find a way to do that in the SDK itself. How do I go about setting the mode in the MarketingCloudSDK in my app?

Answer (score 0):

@nsfeaster, I will point you to:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm .  It's hard to find, but you'll see some routes in REST API > REST Reference > Contacts

There should also be some UI controls in the contacts section of Marketing Cloud's we UI.

The SDK does not offer the "upstream" control of a contact's privacy setting at this time.