# Setting Data Privacy modes from Android MarketingCloud SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android, data-protection-and-privacy

I need to be able to set one of [3 data protection modes](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/data-privacy-android.html) from an Android client that uses the MarketingCloud SDK.  I understand [based on this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232032/salesforce-marketingcloud-sdk-mobilepush-sdk-data-protection-modes) that there is no way to do this via the SDK directly, and that I need to use the Contacts API to do this. [This call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/addContactPreferencesById.htm) seems like a possibility.  The problem is that I can't find any methods to get the `contactId` from the SDK.  I can get a blob of Json from `MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance().getSdkState()`, but it has no `contactId` field.  Does anyone know how to retrieve the `contactId` based off of some field that the SDK will provide?

Once I have the `contactId`, how to I tell Salesforce which one of the 3 data protection modes I want to enable?  In the above call, I only see fields for `contactId` and `hasOptedOutTracking`, which is a boolean.  Is there a more specific call for setting these modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContactID` is not available through the SDK.  Please open a voice of customer request for this feature and, in the interim, you can request the appropriate privacy mode through your account executive.  All devices tied together via Contact Key will be notified and respect the privacy settings indicated by the server-side contact.

Comment: So there is no way to get the ContactID via the REST API based off of some field I have access to in the SDK?

Comment: You have access to `Contact Key`, `System Token` and `Device ID` via the SDK's `RegistrationManager` class (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/6.4/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/registration/RegistrationManager.html)